# How can one monitor RDP connections to a workstations

Tags: windows, rdp

How can one verify if someone is connecting to their workstations (laptops) via RDP ? what policies govern such access? Can such policies be overruled by a local admin of a workstation?? if yes, how can one prevent this?

Comment: Does RDP via Chrome remote desktop, Loge me in, Team viewer etc., would be detected via the group policies? would the listed use same protocols to RDP to a workstation? as a local admin to their workstations can one disable a local group policy, such that network monitoring would not detect these??

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable remote desktop using Group Policy (Computer Configuration, Administrative templates, Windows components, Remote desktop Services, Remote desktop session host, Connections: *Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services* = Disable)
2. Block the RDP connections on Windows Firewall (Computer Configuration, Policies, Administrative Templates, Network, Network Connections, Windows Firewall, Domain Profile: *Windows Firewall: Allow inbound Remote Desktop exceptions* = Disable).
3. Don't give administrative access to your users (at least unless you can trust that they obey your policies).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows *[Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqkTI.png)* to verify if someone is connecting to your Windows workstation via RDP.
The connection will show up with ***[Local Port 3389](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqkTI.png)*** in the *TCP Connections* table of the *Network* tab and the remote machine will be identified by the IP address shown in the *[Remote Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqkTI.png)* column of the table.

Comment: This only works on local machine for the current state. Therefore, it's not really useful if you need to monitor all the laptops all time. Some kind of alert would be better.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I think I mis-understood the question, looking at it from the users's rather than the administrator's point of view.

Comment: True. This is Server Fault; Q/A site for professional sysadmins.

Comment: On a workstation, this is even simpler: if someone else connects to your machine, you get kicked out. :-)